# Formatting INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a few time fields that are INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) Datatypes to store various times of the day.

Currently on normal retrieval, my fields display as such:

+00 19:00:00.000000

How am I able to format this such that it displays as 19:00?

Answer (score 1):

In contradiction to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) you cannot use function `TO_CHAR()` for intervals. It allows to use INTERVAL values but the result is always the same. On another place the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50992) says:

> Interval data types do not have format models.

You can use either [EXTRACT()](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639) function or you can work with Regular Expressions:

```
WITH t AS 
    (SELECT INTERVAL '19' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE AS i FROM dual)
SELECT 
    LPAD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM i), 2, '0')||':'||LPAD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM i), 2, '0'),
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(i, '\d{2}:\d{2}')
FROM t;
```

Usually it is not very smart to use Regular Expression on date/time values. On the other hand, since format of `INTERVAL` does **not** depend on any NLS-Settings it is a feasible option.

Disadvantage of `EXTRACT` is when you have negative intervals. Such an interval would be written like `-19:-30` because every component is returned with minus sign (-). Also be aware that `EXTRACT` returns `NUMBER` values, so you have to pad them with '0' manually.

Comment: There should be no negative intervals. The OP said they use this data type **to store various times of the day**.

Answer (score 1):

You want hours and minutes from an interval. If that interval cannot exceed 24 hours, then you can add the interval to a date without time part and then use `TO_CHAR` to get the formatted hours and minutes:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + myinterval, 'hh24:mi') from mytable
```

If, however, the interval can be larger (e.g. 100 hours and 15 minutes: 100:15), then you'll need another approach:

```
select 
  to_char(extract (day from myinterval) * 24 + extract (hour from myinterval)) ||
  ':' ||
  to_char(extract (minute from myinterval), 'fm00')
from mytable
```

Comment: The interval shouldn't be >= 24 hours; the OP said they use this data type **to store various times of the day**.

Comment: Just because something currently "shouldn't" happen doesn't mean we should ignore robustness in the face of evolving business needs.  Thorsten's response is thoughtful in that it provides (1) just what was asked for, and (2) insight into avoiding a likely future failure mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
substr(to_char(interval_value), 5, 5)
```

where `interval_value` is the column name (incidentally, tables in a relational database don't have fields; they do have columns).

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. It throws me the "string is too long for internal buffer" exception

Comment: @ABB25 - **Huh**? What code are you running? The error does NOT derive from what I wrote in my solution.