# Oracle -- Datatype of column which can store value "13:45"

Tags: oracle, time

We need to store a value "13:45" in the column "Start_Time" of an Oracle table.

Value can be read as 45 minutes past 13:00 hours
Which datatype to be used while creating the table? Also, once queried, we would like to see only the value "13:45".

Comment: check INTERVAL DAY to SECOND

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, I tried the following `code` create table test_time2(
time_col interval HOUR(24) TO MINUTE (59); I got the error: SQL Error: ORA-30088: datetime/interval precision is out of range
30088. 00000 -  "datetime/interval precision is out of range"
*Cause:    The specified datetime/interval precision was not between 0 and 9.
*Action:   Use a value between 0 and 9 for datetime/interval precision.

Comment: You must use a *valid* interval definition, which you may constraint with a CHECK, see example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would make it easier:

```sql
create table t_time_only ( 
   time_col         varchar2(5), 
   time_as_interval INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND invisible
                       generated always as (to_dsinterval('0 '||time_col||':0')),
   constraint check_time 
      check ( VALIDATE_CONVERSION(time_col as date,'hh24:mi')=1 ) 
);
```

Check constraint allows you to validate input strings:

```
SQL> insert into t_time_only values('25:00');
insert into t_time_only values('25:00')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (CHECK_TIME) violated
```

And invisible virtual generated column allows you to make simple arithmetic operations:

```sql
SQL> insert into t_time_only values('15:30');

1 row created.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + time_as_interval as res from t_time_only;

RES
-------------------
2020-09-21 15:30:00
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to store the data in a `DATE` type column. If you are going to be any comparisons against the times (querying, sorting, etc.), you will want to make sure that all of the times are using the same day. It doesn't matter which day as long as they are all the same.

```
CREATE TABLE test_time
(
    time_col    DATE
);

INSERT INTO test_time
     VALUES (TO_DATE ('13:45', 'HH24:MI'));

INSERT INTO test_time
     VALUES (TO_DATE ('8:45', 'HH24:MI'));
```

#### Test Query

```
  SELECT time_col,
         TO_CHAR (time_col, 'HH24:MI')                                 AS just_time,
         24 * (time_col - LAG (time_col) OVER (ORDER BY time_col))     AS difference_in_hours
    FROM test_time
ORDER BY time_col;
```

#### Test Results

```
    TIME_COL    JUST_TIME    DIFFERENCE_IN_HOURS
____________ ____________ ______________________
01-SEP-20    08:45
01-SEP-20    13:45                             5
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance EJ Egyed. However, we would like to see the values in the table as 08:45 or 13:45 without having to format the same using to_char. Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: You would like to see ...  without using to_char.  Sorry, but that's how oracle works.  You _could_ store it as a varchar2, but then you lose any internal integrity constraints _and_ lose the ability to to time-based comparisons.  what's your objection to using to_char?  It's just a few characters of coding.

Comment: @EdStevens Well, technically i understand the need of using to_char. I completely undersatnd. However, when non-technical person sees the data, they will question as to why they see values in format mm/dd/yyyy instead of 08:45 :)

Comment: This seems to by a problem with `HH`  and `HH24`. Please check also the alternative [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996863/4808122) - this seems to by most flexible one, as it combines the VARCHAR data type with the INTERVAL

Comment: I understand non-tech users.  But that still begs the question of what is wrong with using the to_char function?  Even if non-technical users are writing their own queries, they need to be taught that is how it needs to be coded.

Answer (score 0):

Table Definition using `INTERVAL`

```
create table tab
(tm INTERVAL DAY(1) to SECOND(0));
```

Input value as literal

```
insert into tab (tm) values (INTERVAL  '13:25'  HOUR TO MINUTE );
```

Input value dynamically

```
 insert into tab (tm) values ( (NUMTODSINTERVAL(13, 'hour') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(26, 'minute')) );
```

Output

you may either `EXTRACT` the hour and minute

```
 EXTRACT(HOUR FROM tm) int_hour,
 EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM tm) int_minute
```

or use formatted output with a trick by adding some fixed DATE

```
to_char(DATE'2000-01-01'+tm,'hh24:mi') int_format
```

which gives

```
13:25
13:26
```

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45183024/4808122) for other formating options `HH24:MI`

The used `INTERVAL` definition may store seconds as well - if this is not acceptable, add `CHECK CONSTRAINT` e.g. as follows (adjust as requiered)

```
tm INTERVAL DAY(1) to SECOND(0) 
    constraint "wrong interval" check (tm <= INTERVAL  '23:59'  HOUR TO MINUTE and EXTRACT(SECOND FROM tm) = 0 )
```

This rejects the following as invalid input

```
insert into tab (tm) values (INTERVAL  '13:25:30'  HOUR TO SECOND );
-- ORA-02290: check constraint (X.wrong interval) violated
```

Comment: This is really great when I've to manually insert the values into table. However, I generally have to import data from excel file and when I tried the same, I get the following error: `Data Types INTERVAL DAY,  not supported for import`... Please advice. Thanks

Comment: @VinodKrishnaC this should be the *very first inromation* you provide in the question - the need for bulk import. Also let us know what operation do you need to do with the value. If only the output in the `HH24:MI` format is required - you may use `VARCHAR2` with the least problems...

Comment: I'm really sorry that I missed to mention that the data was inserted mostly using bulk import. I was only thinking that the issue is with the datatype that I'm choosing to store the values. On the operations, we would use `asc or desc or difference` on the values mostly. Also, I redefined the column with datatype `varchar2`. However, when I imported, it stored the value as 11:55 while my input data was 23:55.. Please advice again. Thanks